# Show full date when asking for file list SFTP in cURL

Tags: date, curl, sftp

I'm using cURL with a STFP server and I'm trying to get a correct date format for my following process.

At this point, when i'm asking for file list I get this :

```
-rw-r--r--    1 0        0          718541 Dec 24  18:25 myfile.png
```

The thing is I also need to get the year, but the year is only available if the file is older than a year, and in this case, replace the hour:minute with the year

```
-rw-r--r--    1 0        0          718541 Dec 24  2000 myoldfile.png
```

In FTP there is the parameter "MLSD", that can format the date that show full date but I didn't find a equivalent for SFTP

Given that the result looks like an `ls -la` unix command, I try to use `ls -la --full-time` but this parameter doesn't seem to work on SFTP server.

Is there any way to retrieve file list that include date : year month day hour minute

Whatever the format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using the curl option `CURLOPT_FILETIME`.

By giving the name of the file you want, it retrieves a `long` that can be cast on a `time_t`.

Here's a sample of how it work (that can be find in curl example code):

Setup the connection

```
curl_easy_setopt(mHandleCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "sftp://192.168.1.10/myfile.txt");
curl_easy_setopt(mHandleCurl, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);   
curl_easy_setopt(mHandleCurl, CURLOPT_PORT, 22);
curl_easy_setopt(mHandleCurl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, sUsername);
curl_easy_setopt(mHandleCurl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, sPassword);
```

Set an empty callback - looks mandatory

```
curl_easy_setopt(mHandleCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, throw_away);
curl_easy_setopt(mHandleCurl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, 1L);

curl_easy_perform(mHandleCurl); // Perform
```

Callback code:

```
static size_t throw_away(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *data)
{
   (void)ptr;
   (void)data;
   /* we are not interested in the headers itself,
      so we only return the size we would have saved ... */
   return (size_t)(size * nmemb);
}
```

And then get the file timestamp

```
long lTimestamp = -1;
curl_easy_getinfo(mHandleCurl, CURLINFO_FILETIME, &lTimestamp);
```

And cast it to time_t or struct tm to get full timestamp access

```
time_t t_filetimestamp = (time_t) lTimestamp;

struct tm* tm_filetimestamp;
tm_filetimestamp = localtime(&t_filetimestamp);
```

Comment: OK, but it does not allow you to retrieve the timestamp from a directory listing. You have to call it for every file separatelly.

Answer (score 2):

It does not look like you can make curl produce full timestamps with SFTP protocol.

But it is a limitation of curl, not SFTP protocol or server as such.

SFTP server provides full timestamps (and other attributes) for each file. Additionally it provides textual "description" of the file. curl prints that description (and discards the full timestamps and other attributes). OpenSSH SFTP server produces the "description" in the format you are seeing. So the behavior you are seeing is a combination of OpenSSH SFTP server and curl.

Using another SFTP client or SFTP library (in Python, PHP, etc) that can make use of full timestamps provided by the server will help.